# Deserialization issue for datetime field

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

What is the best way to deserialize an JSON

I have the following JSON

```
"_created" : { 
                "$dt": "2013-03-26T16:45:20Z" 
             }
```

and i want get field of object, like this - `DataTime Created {get; set;}`

Question for json.net http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx experts

Comment: which tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is creating JsonConvertor

```
public class MongoDbDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

            return jObject["$dt"].Value<DateTime>();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and used it with property

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MongoDbDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JSON serializer/deserializer from [NewtonSoft](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/N_Newtonsoft_Json.htm), worked ok for me.

[Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) package

[MediaTypeFormatter example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-JSONNET-with-ASPNET-b2423706)

Add following MediaTypeFormatter to the GlobalConfiguration like so:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonFormatter());
```

MediaTypeFormatter:

```
public class JsonFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    private const string WesternEuropeStandardTime = "W. Europe Standard Time";
    private TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo;

    public JsonFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        this.timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(WesternEuropeStandardTime);
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        Task<object> task = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            };

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(readStream);
            JsonTextReader jreader = new JsonTextReader(sr);

            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            ser.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter(this.timeZoneInfo) { DateTimeFormat = "o" });

            return ser.Deserialize(jreader, type);
        });

        return task;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                value, 
                Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonConverter[1] { new DateTimeConverter(this.timeZoneInfo) { DateTimeFormat = "o" } });

            byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);
            writeStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            writeStream.Flush();
        });

        return task;
    }

    private class DateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        private TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo;

        public DateTimeConverter(TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo)
        {
            this.timeZoneInfo = timeZoneInfo;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            DateTime? date = value as DateTime?;
            if (date.HasValue && DateTime.MinValue != date.Value && DateTime.MaxValue != date.Value)
            {
                TimeSpan timeZoneOffset = this.timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(date.Value);
                value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date.Value - timeZoneOffset, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }

            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            object result = base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

            DateTime? date = result as DateTime?;
            if (date.HasValue && DateTime.MinValue != date.Value && DateTime.MaxValue != date.Value)
            {
                TimeSpan timeZoneOffset = this.timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(date.Value);
                result = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date.Value + timeZoneOffset, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if u can see, problem here  "_created" : { "$dt": "2013-03-26T16:45:20Z" } - here  "$dt": "2013-03-26T16:45:20Z", it is not a string!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `json.NET`

try to `serialize` a `datetime` field or an `object` consisting of `datetime` field like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
            };
string serializedObject= Newtonsoft.Json
                     .JsonConvert
                     .SerializeObject(data, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

it works without a glitch, if serialization has been done using `JSON.NET` :)

and then you can successfully deserialize it back

```
var myobject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedObject);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking about a JSON parser in C#, then that is more of a Google thing. Go search there. There are loads of them available.

If you're asking about how to parse this string into DateTime, then `DateTime.TryParse()` will help you. You can help it by supplied string format, something like `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

Comment: when deserializing a string into an object, consists of a datetime field, it usually gives error unless it is handled. you have no clue about this question hence a downvote :)